# jquery slideUp button inside FAQs div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that works great:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#faqs li').each(function() {
    var tis = $(this),
      state = false,
      answer = tis.next('div').hide().css('height', 'auto').slideUp();
    tis.click(function() {
      state = !state;
      answer.slideToggle(state);
      tis.toggleClass('active', state);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#faqs h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#faqs li.active {
  color: #d74646;
}
#faqs div {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#faqs div p {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.slideup:hover {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faqs">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h3>Question</h3>
    </li>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit purto convenire deseruisse no. Vis ei unum similique reprimique, dicant nonumy no eos, has quis definiebas ullamcorper an. Ad cum eros voluptua. Ponderum voluptatum reprimique pro id, ne usu delenit invenire, et movet
        facilis perfecto quo.
        <br />
        <br />

        <span class="slideup">Slide up</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <li>
      <h3>Question</h3>
    </li>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit purto convenire deseruisse no. Vis ei unum similique reprimique, dicant nonumy no eos, has quis definiebas ullamcorper an. Ad cum eros voluptua. Ponderum voluptatum reprimique pro id, ne usu delenit invenire, et movet
        facilis perfecto quo.
        <br />
        <br />

        <span class="slideup">Slide up</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <li>
      <h3>Question</h3>
    </li>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit purto convenire deseruisse no. Vis ei unum similique reprimique, dicant nonumy no eos, has quis definiebas ullamcorper an. Ad cum eros voluptua. Ponderum voluptatum reprimique pro id, ne usu delenit invenire, et movet
        facilis perfecto quo.
        <br />
        <br />

        <span class="slideup">Slide up</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </ol>
```

The problem is I would like to have a link at the bottom inside the FAQs div (Slide up) that would slide up the answer... and i can't figure out how to do that... any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: $(".slideup").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().parent().slideUp();
});

this would slide up the div again?
http://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/hsbeq8vd/

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#faqs li').each(function() {
    var tis = $(this),
      state = false,
      answer = tis.next('div').hide().css('height', 'auto').slideUp(),
      slideup = $(tis.next('div').find('span.slideup'));
      console.log(slideup);
    tis.click(function() {
      state = !state;
      answer.slideToggle(state);
      tis.toggleClass('active', state);
    });
    slideup.click(function(){
      state = !state;
      answer.slideToggle(state);
      tis.toggleClass('active', state);
    })
  });
});
```